# Prove that X = $\{n \in \mathbb{Z}\mid n+5$ is odd$\}$ is the set of all even integers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I was wondering if I am doing the prove to this question correctly..

My attempt: Pick Y to be set of all even integers, so then we have $Y = \{2m\mid m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Then I show that $X \subseteq Y$.

Let $a \in X$ where $a=2k+1$. Then $a+5 = 2k+1+5 = 2k+6 = 2(k+3)$. Here we see that $a$ must be even. Therefore, $X \subseteq Y$ holds.

Is this correct, or am I off a bit?

Comment: The question says "is the set of even integers", which means you must prove that $Y \subset X$. However, that is just as easy as what you've done so far (which is fine). Also, note  that $k \in \mathbb Z$ should be mentioned, otherwise this is incorrect.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope that you found the reverse part just as easy, if not easier. Oh, +1.

Comment: Yeah it shouldn't be a problem lol

Comment: You don't know that $a$ is odd.  And if $a+5$ is even then $a$ is NOT in X.  Yo need so say that $a \in X$ so $a+5$ is odd (NOT $a$) and so $a+5 = 2k + 1$ and $a = 2k - 4 = 2(k-1)$ is even.  Then you have proven $X \subset Y$.  Now you must prove $Y\subset X$. That would be correct....

Comment: .... but it'd be more efficient to prove $a$ is even if and only if $a+5$ is odd.  $a$ is even $\iff$ $a = 2k$ for some $k$ $iff$ $a+5 = 2k+5 = (2k+4)+1 = 2(k+2) + 1= 2m+1; m=k+2\iff a+5 $ is odd.  So then $X$ consists of precisely the even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define the subsets of $\mathbb Z$

even numbers like this  $\mathcal E:\begin{cases}0\in \mathcal E\\e\in\mathcal E\iff e+2\in\mathcal E\end{cases}\quad$  and odd numbers $\mathcal O=1+\mathcal E$

- $0\in X$ because $0+5=1+(0+2+2)\in\mathcal O$
- $x\in X\iff x+5\in \mathcal O\iff \exists e\in\mathcal E\mid x+5=1+e\overset{(*)}{\iff} (x+2)+5=\underbrace{1+\underbrace{(e+2)}_{\in\ \mathcal E}}_{\in\ \mathcal O}\iff x+2\in X$

So $X=\mathcal E$.

(*) *to be thorough, we should also state $e\in\mathcal E\iff e-2\in\mathcal E$, I took a shortcut there... My purpose was to show that we don't necessarily need the $2n,2n+1$ stuff.*